# How to compare 2 columns with similar data (eg. not same order, with comma)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm dealing with a dirty database, that has not normalized data, and has a column with a name like

**"john kevin smith"**  that I need to compare with another column (from other table) that could have **"Kevin john smith"** or **"smith, kevin john"** or the same as the original, and based on that I need to figure out if they point to the same record.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this with SQL Server 2012.

I have been testing with the JaroWinkler function without luck, I also tried with the fnSplit function, but that doesn't seem to do the trick, I believe I might have to first somehow normalize them, then separate them all and then compare between each other, but I'm drawing a blank on the process.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

with a split function and some replaces I'm able to "normalize" the columns, and receive the results in a table function like this:

[image]

now I just need to figure out how to compare with another set of values, as I'll get something similar when executing to the column I want to compare with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comparison you can just use the `EXISTS` clause.

***Sample data***

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
    VAL_A varchar(200),
    VAL_B varchar(200)
);

INSERT INTO TEST (VAL_A, VAL_B) VALUES
('john kevin smith', 'Kevin john smith'),
('john kevin smith', 'Kevin, john smith'),
('Alpha beta gamma', 'beta delta alpha');
```

***Query:***

```
SELECT VAL_A, VAL_B
FROM TEST
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT value FROM [dbo].[fn_Split](VAL_A, ' ')
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT value FROM [dbo].[fn_Split]((REPLACE(VAL_B,',','')), ' ')
)
OR 
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT value FROM [dbo].[fn_Split]((REPLACE(VAL_B,',','')), ' ')
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT value FROM [dbo].[fn_Split](VAL_A, ' ')
```

This will return the matching rows.

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
| VAL_A             | VAL_B             |
+-------------------+-------------------+
| john kevin smith  | Kevin john smith  |
| john kevin smith  | Kevin, john smith |
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

in the output, you can notice that `alpha,beta,gamma,delta` combination is not appearing as those are not matching. You can change `NOT EXISTS` to `EXISTS` if you want non matching rows.

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=078888d74b318faa9c9191e93feec8c6)

You can use the `joins` if the other column is coming from another table. Also use the `REPLACE` statements accordingly.

Comment: wow, I wish I could upvote this more than once, great response! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> A table-valued function that **splits a string into rows of substrings,
>   based on a specified separator character**

```
SELECT a.Value
FROM STRING_SPLIT('john kevin smith', ' ') a
INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT('Kevin john smith', ' ') b on a.Value = b.Value
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d1b0901929ac492282b02aadadf411d)

[image]

Comment: actually, SQL Server 2012 does not support String_Split(), I've thought of it :(

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea.. what you could do is to do a find and replace of all spaces with a comma for that field in each of the table. Place the results of each table into a separate #temp table.  Once you have done that.. do a string_split (of fnSplit) depending on SQL version and order then alphabetically.

Now join these tables based on the column value and see where you get at

Comment: I don't entirely understand this